# Can you subtract two integers using multiplication and division?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

The multiplication operation is traditionally defined as "repeated addition", and division (with remainder) can be defined using repeated subtraction. Can we define subtraction the other way round? i.e., given two integers, can we calculate x-y using only operations of multiplication and division on x and y?

Comment: There are only two "natural" operations, adding and multiplying. In general (rings) they are not connected in the same way as they do in $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, multiplying a matrix by itself has "nothing" to do with adding of this matrix to itself.

Comment: @barakmanos  Ofir Schnabel already provided some information about the "simple", "natural" operations. Division is in fact a multiplication by the inverse of a number (which is another number), if we are talking about numbers... About the patronizing, a simple search on google gives hundreds of answers. And since english is not my mother tongue, I am sometimes making basic errors.

Comment: For example, start with  $m-n=\log_2\left(\frac{2^m}{2^n}\right)$

Comment: By "repeated subtraction", do you mean subtracting the divisor from the dividend repeatedly until you get zero, and counting how many times you subtracted?

Comment: Some would argue that treating multiplication as repeated addition is [quite wrong](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_06_08.htm).